# c# DI Unity Container how to resolve dependent object

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

We have following implementation of IProduct & ILogger class. Manager classes are being used as communication channel. We have used unity as given below to resolve manager class but it giving following error-

```
===================unity configuration==========

IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<ILogger, FileLogger>("File");
container.RegisterType<ILogger, BDLogger>("DB");

container.RegisterType<IProduct, ProductA>("productA");
container.RegisterType<IProduct, ProductB>("productB");

container.RegisterType<ProducManager>(new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IProduct>("productA")));

container.Resolve<ProducManager>("productA");

========================================================
```

> "Resolution of the dependency failed, type = \"usingDI.IProduct\",
>   name = \"productA\".\r\nException occurred while: while
>   resolving.\r\nException is: InvalidOperationException - The current
>   type, usingDI.ILogger, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are
>   you missing a type
>   mapping?\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\nAt the
>   time of the exception, the container was:\r\n\r\n  Resolving
>   usingDI.ProductA,productA (mapped from usingDI.IProduct, productA)\r\n
>   Resolving parameter \"logger\" of constructor
>   usingDI.ProductA(usingDI.ILogger logger)\r\n    Resolving
>   usingDI.ILogger,(none)\r\n"}"

Please suggest me best way to resolve dependency for manager classes.

```
public interface IProduct
{
    void dosomething();
}

public class ProducManager
{
    IProduct _product;
    public ProducManager(IProduct product)
    {
        _product = product;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _product.dosomething();
    }
}

public class ProductA : IProduct
{
    ILogger _logger;
    public ProductA(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void dosomething()
    {

        try
        {
            //code
            //
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.WriteLog(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class ProductB : IProduct
{
    ILogger _logger;
    public ProductB(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void dosomething()
    {

        try
        {
            //code
            //
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.WriteLog(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
public class LogManager
{
    ILogger _logger;
    public LogManager(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void WriteLog(string exception)
    {
        _logger.WriteLog(exception);
    }
}

public interface ILogger
{
    void WriteLog(string exception);
}

public class FileLogger : ILogger
{

    public void WriteLog(string exception)
    {

    }
}

public class BDLogger : ILogger
{

    public void WriteLog(string exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: ADDED UNITY CONFIGURATION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a type mapping for your interface `ILogger`. Otherwise does Unity not now which implementation of `ILogger` it should use (see your exception).

Here´s an example registering the interface `ILogger` with a mapping to `FileLogger`:

```
_container.RegisterType<ILogger, FileLogger>();

IProduct product = _container.Resolve<ProductA>(); //ILogger is injected to Product
```

Comment: Thanks Jehof. IProduct have different product implementation and inside the specific product class we need to use some other classes  object like FileLogger which are derived from some interface having different implentation. When we resolve ProductManager Class for ProductA want to resolve FileLogger and for ProductB DBLogger. Please suggest.

Comment: Then you need to do a similar registration for ProductA which has an InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<ILogger>("File")) and also ProductB.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, you are right. But finally i have decided to use CI for ProductA,ProductB instead of registering manager class.